Calculating spread on a par rate curve given bond’s coupon and yield
In Tuckman and Serrat’s Fixed Income Securities, they give an example of a bond and state its coupon and yield.
They also provide an HQM par rate curve and quote the bond’s spread to this curve.
How would the spread to this curve be calculated?
From the coupon and yield, you can calculate the price of the bond. Similarly, from the HQM par rate curve, you can calculate spot rates and forward rates. But it is not clear how one can use all this information to compute a spread to the curve.
A step-by-step breakdown
would be helpful.

Z-Spread or OA-Spread (with no optionality)
In Python's rateslib you can make the following calculation:
Define a bond and a curve:
#PYTHON
from rateslib import FixedRateBond, Curve

bond = FixedRateBond(
    effective=dt(2023, 3, 7), termination="10y",
    fixed_rate=3.0, spec="ukt"
)

curve = Curve(
    nodes={dt(2023, 3, 7): 1.0, dt(2033, 9, 7): 0.68},
    calendar="ldn", convention="act365f",
)

Use the curve to price the bond's current implied mid-market discounted cashflows and derive an OASpread based an assumed price of par (100.0):
bond.rate(curves=curve, metric="clean_price")
# 94.14639360179893
bond.oaspread(curves=curve, price=100.00)
# -69.37792098276168

You can double check this is valid by shift-ing the curve and re-pricing the bond:
shifted_curve = curve.shift(-69.37792098276168)
bond.rate(curves=shifted_curve, metric="clean_price")
# 100.00000000000647

So what is actually going on?
Firstly you must define what is a "spread of 1bp to a curve". This is a very important mathematical consideration. Rateslib defines it as adding 1bp to every overnight rate implied by the discount curve. Defining it this way is helpful because it establishes consistent properties of a metric space. Defining it in an alternate way, such as to suggest that the instruments parametrising the Curve, e.g. the 5y swap rate and 10y swap rate are increased by 1bp is very unhelpful because this leads to arbitrary relationships dependent upon those calibrating instruments.
Now you have to derive the actual amount of basis points that the curve needs to shift by in order to re-price the bond at the target price. This requires an iterative root solving algorithm. There is often no closed form solution for this problem.
The price of your bond evaluated at the current curve is:
$$P(C)$$
You are seeking a target price, $P_{tgt}$, which is equal to a price evaluated with a curve shifted by $z$ basis points, i.e.:
$$h(z) = P(C + zC_{1bp}) - P_{tgt} = 0.0 $$
One such possible algorithm is Newton-Raphson. Start with an initial guess e.g. z_0 = 0.0 and apply:
$$ z_{i+1} = z_i - \frac{h(z_i)}{h'(z_i)} $$
I can show you the first iteration that rateslib would perform by evaluating the needed gradient for the algorithm using automatic differentiation:
curve._set_ad_order(1)
sensitivity_curve = curve.shift(Dual(0.0, ["z"], []), composite=False)
p = bond.rate(curves=sensitivity_curve, metric="clean_price")
dh_dp = gradient(p, ["z"])
# -0.08162224

Thus,
$$ z_1 = 0.0 - (94.14639 - 100.0) / -0.08162224 = -71.715 bps$$
Maybe 3-5 more iterations will get to -69.3779...
Yield-Yield spread
The yield-yield spread is just the YTM minus the par rate on the curve. Very easy to calculate, not as mathematically consistent as using the OASpread.
In this case the YY spread would be -73.6862.. bps
swap = IRS(effective=dt(2023, 3, 7), termination="10y", spec="gbp_irs")
swap.rate(curves=curve)
# 3.736855699417951
bond.ytm(price=100.0, settlement=dt(2023, 3, 8))
# 2.9999929845112567


Brent usually converges faster than Newton-Raphson, which sometimes helps.
